# Where to upload XML file for Highchart table

Tags: php, xml, highcharts

I am trying to create an Highchart table based on a XML file. However I did not succeeded yet. I am using the example of the Highcharts website.

This are my scripts:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
```

Than I am uploaded the following data.xml file to my website www.example.com/data.xml, containing the following data:

```
<chart>
<categories>
<item>Apples</item>
<item>Pears</item>
<item>Oranges</item>
<item>Bananas</item>
</categories>
<series>
<name>John</name>
<data>
<point>8</point>
<point>4</point>
<point>6</point>
<point>5</point>
</data>
</series>
<series>
<name>Jane</name>
<data>
<point>3</point>
<point>4</point>
<point>2</point>
<point>3</point>
</data>
</series>
<series>
<name>Joe</name>
<data>
<point>86</point>
<point>76</point>
<point>79</point>
<point>77</point>
</data>
</series>
<series>
<name>Janet</name>
<data>
<point>3</point>
<point>16</point>
<point>13</point>
<point>15</point>
</data>
</series>
</chart>
```

And this is the script I am using:

```
// Load the data XML file 
 $.get('data.xml', function(xml) {

// Split the lines
var $xml = $(xml);

// push categories
$xml.find('categories item').each(function(i, category) {
    options.xAxis.categories.push($(category).text());
});

// push series
$xml.find('series').each(function(i, series) {

    var seriesOptions = {
        name: $(series).find('name').text(),
        data: []
    };

    // push data points
    $(series).find('data point').each(function(i, point) {
        seriesOptions.data.push(
            parseInt($(point).text())
        );
    });

    // add it to the options
    options.series.push(seriesOptions);
});

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
 });
```

What am I doing wrong? Did I upload the CSV file in the correct folder? Or do I make other mistakes?

Comment: Anything in console?

Comment: What do you mean anything in console? Please elaborate

Comment: Open JavaScript console in your browser and let us know if you have there any errors. If so, copy them to the question.

Comment: It seems to be a path related issue , check whether you put this xml in a folder from where your page can invoke it. check error console if it has 404 -file not found error (in network tab, if using chrome)

Comment: Are your XML and webpage (with table) at the same server?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < It says error on line 339, but that line is empty

@SebastianBochan Yes, they are in the same server

Comment: The error is on:
$.get('data.xml', function(xml) {</p>

So it can not get the data.xml isnt it?

Comment: Why you have  </p> in function ?

Comment: Because I am using wordpress. I think it's the problem that im using wordpress. I uploaded the XML file to the Wordpress root. But the XML file should be in the same folder as the page. However, Wordpress stores pages in MYSQL. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Your javascript should be in <script></script> tags and not mixed with html like you have. Maybe simpler is using [Highcharts.cloud](http://cloud.highcharts.com/) ?

Comment: Try using the full link in your `$.get` function: 
$.get('www.example.com/data.xml', function(xml)